# Can't open Disk Management with USB drive plugged in

Tags: windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, diskpart, easeus-partition-manager

Running Win 10 Home, I recently formatted a USB drive with EaseUS Partition Master, nothing fancy, just a single NTFS volume. Now whenever the drive is plugged in, EaseUS can't detect it, Windows doesn't assign the drive a letter and Disk Management won't open (hangs on 'Connecting to Virtual Disk Service'). Trying to run diskpart in cmd doesn't get beyond the 'On computer: PCNAME' line. All these work fine with the USB device unplugged. The drive appears in Device Manager where I've tried uninstalling the device and restarting, to no avail.

Comment: Sure seems dead. You can try formatting on another machine, or with another tool such as DiskGenius, but it's unlikely to work. BTW, why NTFS? It's generally *not* advised for flash drives.

Comment: Last time I had same thing with an HDD it turned out to have a lot of errors. Looks very similar to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on an Ubuntu distro. I noticed in the Disks utility the 64GB drive had two partitions each 52GB! Disks wasn't able to delete or mount the partitions, it just hang, but I was able to delete the first partition using fdisk (following [this tutorial](https://dottheslash.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/deleting-all-partitions-on-a-usb-drive/)) then the device mounted that partition no problem.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo su`
2. Type `fdisk -l` and note the USB drive letter.
3. Type `fdisk /dev/sdx` (replacing x with the releavnt drive letter)
4. Type `d` to delete a partition
5. Type `1` to select the 1st partition and press enter
6. Type `d` to proceed to delete another partition if you need to remove any others (fdisk should automatically select the second partition)
7. Type `w` to write the information to the USB key
8. Type `umount /dev/sdx` (replacing x with your drive letter)

Comment: You should include what you did to solve your problem in the event the tutorial isn’t available (like right now). Besides, link only answers, even if they are accepted can be deleted by the community for being link only answers